# Enter Key as Java Application Form Submission - JFrame

Tags: java, forms, keyboard, jframe, enter

I'm trying to make one sample code to submit one text field when I press the "Enter" key at one Java Application.

I'm using JFrame and the following code:

```
package com.sh.st;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;




public class SearchScreen extends JFrame{

    JButton btsearch;
    JLabel lbsearch;
    JTextField txtsearch;
    JPanel p1;

    public SearchScreen(){

    //Button Creation
    btsearch= new JButton("Search");


    //Label Creation
    lbsearch= new JLabel("Type Keywords in english to be searched below:");


    //TextBox   
    txtsearch= new JTextField();


    //Pane Creation 
    p1=new JPanel();
    p1.setBackground(Color.gray);

    //Pane Components
    p1.add(lbsearch);
    p1.add(txtsearch);
    p1.add(btsearch);

    btsearch.setEnabled(true);

    //Adding JPaneel    
    getContentPane().add(p1);

    //JFrame Setup
    setSize(300,300);
    setTitle("SHST");

    //JFrame Layout Setup   
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));


    btsearch.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    }

}
```

but the problem is, as a virtual key I need to hold at the same time "alt" and this is too unconfortable and not intuitive as an user.

I tryed to take a look in a lot of pages here at stack and google but none of them gave me the answer. I saw some commands such as "addKeyListener" but I couldn't do until now what I want.

Thanks for the help

**Edit [TOPIC SOLVED]**:

```
    package com.sh.st;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;


public class EventSearch extends SearchScreen{

    String query;



    public EventSearch(){

        txtsearch.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, key);
        txtsearch.getActionMap().put(key, enterAction);


}

    Action enterAction = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {

                HttpRequest http = new HttpRequest(CatchQuery());

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace(); //print failure
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HTTP request failure.");
            }   
        }};
     String key = "ENTER";
     KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key);



            public String CatchQuery(){
                query=txtsearch.getText();
                this.dispose();
                return query;
            }



}
```

Comment: what form? html input form? gui-form?

Comment: What kind of form are you talking about? I know how it is done in swing, but it seems you are not using swing. JSP? You have to be more precise (or at least add a tag).

Comment: @Axel Yes I'm trying to do this with swing, I edited the post. Sry for the low information.

Comment: More code might be useful showing where you are using this and how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `KeyBindings` [How to use KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Here is a piece of code

```
final JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
Action enterAction = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //do something
    }};
 String key = "ENTER";
 KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key);
 textfield.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, key);
 textfield.getActionMap().put(key, enterAction);
```

Comment: I'm having difficulties with "enterAction", tryed to create one variable but this messed other part of the code that was working, check edita one

Comment: @VictorOliveira 1) i add the keyBinding to the textfield, for example if you don't want to have focus and press key, add this keybinding to the container for example a JPanel or frame.getContentPane() , 2) if(e.getSource()==btsearch) this always be false, cause you are adding the action to another component

Comment: I did as you say but now since AbstractAction come from one abstract method dispose is being rejected CatchQuery cos it returns one string - Check Edit 2

Comment: @VictorOliveira your edit2 even compile, you have to put it inside a method or constructor

Comment: thanks for the the help, now It's working perfectly, I made one third edit with the full code working, if u could vote up I would be very pleasure, I'm sure this is gonna help someone else. Thank you very much

Comment: your code may works, but it is not ok at all..at least what you post.. delete `implements ActionListener` and follow `Code Conventions` `` `catchQuery` should not dispose window i think.

Comment: Sorry for that, as you see I'm not PRO yet with java and programmation at all - Now I think it's completely perfect. thanks again

Comment: The last one? Why so? It's running perfect here, working out as it should be :x

Comment: @VictorOliveira ah yes it's compile but they are like `global variables` exists in all your class , may be they should only be created in the constructor as local variables :D

Answer (score 0):

Just add an ActionListener to your text field:

```
//TextBox   
txtsearch = new JTextField();
txtsearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // code when enter is pressed in text field
  }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't answer, actionListener I was already using based on virtual key...it's just implemented in another class

Comment: Then I don't understand what you want to do. At least this is how I do it, and it works in my code...